# Let user pick background Image/Color on node form

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I would like to allow my users to choose a background image or color for a node. I created a content type with two fields: 'background image' of type image, and 'background color' of type color field.

I can retrieve the values of the fields on my module but how can I pass them to my stylesheet? Should I use the `style` attribute of my HTML elements?

The background color can be any color so I can't precreate css classes, or files.

Any idea on how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it in your  node.tpl.php. You can add the style attribute directly to the attributes array in a [node preprocess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7).

in your `template.php` , load(add css file ) or insert in-line css style

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $type = $variables['type'];
   // dpm($$variables['node']);
  // as example
 if($color=$variables['node']->field_color['und'][0]['value']){
 $css = "p {background-color: $color }";
 drupal_add_css($css, 'inline');
   }
 }
```

you can do something like this .I hope this solution get you some good clue .